# Merge four CMYK images into one RGB Image Java

Tags: java, image, image-processing, bufferedimage, java-2d

Thanks in advance for any help you could provide to me, and sorry for my bad english.

I know there's a lot of questions about this topic, but I have looked a lot on all the Internet (and StackOverflow too) but I haven't found any answer for this...

I have four images; each one of them is in the TYPE_BYTE_GRAY color model.  I have loaded these four images using this code:

```
int numElems = 4;
BufferedImage[] img = new BufferedImage[numElems];
for(int i=0;i<numElems;i++){
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(args[i]);
    img[i] = ImageIO.read(in);
    in.close();
}
```

Just ImageIO read... I need to "merge" the four images into one RGB image... Each one of the images is one channel from a CMYK image. All these images have equal dimensions.  I have converted the four images to one CMYK image using this code:

```
for(int j=0;j<img[0].getHeight();j++){
    //Read current point color...
    for(int k=0;k<numElems;k++){
        colPunto[k] = (img[k].getRGB(i, j) & 0xFF);
    }

    int colorPunto = convertComponentsRGB(colPunto);

    //Now, I set the point...
    out.setRGB(i, j, colorPunto);
    }
}
```

This function "convertComponentsRGB" is just natural math to convert CMYK color to RGB Color...

```
function convertComponentsRGB(int[] pointColor){
float cyan = (float)pointColor[0] / (float)255;
float magenta = (float)pointColor[1] / (float)255;
float yellow = (float)pointColor[2] / (float)255;
float black = (float)pointColor[3] / (float)255;

float c = min(1f,cyan * (1f - black) + black); //minimum value
float m = min(1f,magenta * (1f - black) + black); //minimum value
float y = min(1f, yellow * (1f - black) + black); //minimum value

result[0] = Math.round(255f*(1f - c));
result[1] = Math.round(255f*(1f - m));
result[2] = Math.round(255f*(1f - y));

    return (result[0]<<16) | (result[1]<<8) | result[2];
}
```

The problem here is... speed.  It takes 12 seconds to process one image, because we've to read each pixel and write each pixel, and I think "getRGB" and "setRGB" functions aren't very quick (or, it's just a best way to achieve this).

¿How can I achieve this? I have reading a lot about ColorModel, filters, but I still don't understand how to achieve this in a better time.

Comment: You could compute 1/255f once for all images and use it in a multiplication, instead of making a division. Try it and report back. :)

Comment: Ok... it's better by 10%... But the thing is that I want to know if there's a way to achieve this using Raster Images, Filters, or something like this... Pure Java2D

Comment: You do not even need the floats. I would guess this could be about 10 times faster if you only did it with integers.

Comment: Sorry the question, but... how? Any ideas?

Comment: Nope.... equal time to convert... I'm not sure if integer or float numbers have different times...

Comment: Would it work to do everything using integers, as in `red=255-cyan; green=255-magenta; blue=255-yellow`, then scale for black by (a) multiplying each result by `(255-black)` and (b) dividing each result by 255?

Comment: From my experience, `getRGB` and `setRGB` are indeed slow. Reading and writing the data buffers directly is your best bet to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getData%28%29) and [`setData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setData%28java.awt.image.Raster%29) to speed up access to the pixels vs. `getRGB` and `setRGB`.

There's no need to convert the CMYK to floating point and back, you can work directly with the pixel values:

```
function convertComponentsRGB(int[] pointColor){
    int r = max(0, 255 - (pointColor[0] + pointColor[3]));
    int g = max(0, 255 - (pointColor[1] + pointColor[3]));
    int b = max(0, 255 - (pointColor[2] + pointColor[3]));

    return (r<<16) | (g<<8) | b;
}
```